# Where is stored index file example in python Django?

Tags: python, django

Starting study Django, i try check all files of project example installation

For example when we install and run Apache with PHP we can see the tipical `index.html` on `/var/www/html/index.html`.

I know Django run over `MTV` pattern and it is new fo me, like `MVC` too.

I try understand how script call and mount the `presentation page` in web.

Well the question is, where is stored, the `index.html` it we see when we start Django, the example page?

Where is stored the bellow html?

[image]

Comment: `/var/www/html/index.html` has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP. That's a file that your web server (or maybe the packager for your web server on your distribution) uses as its default. Don't assume that Django is anything like PHP + Apache. I suggest you go through the [official Django tutorial](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/). It's quite good.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Comment: @Chris i think speak not cleary,  i know php is not like Python, that is first thing i discovery from Python... The path i was mentioned is the standart html from Apache, now i search from standart index page Django, the page with Rocket, you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template html page you see when you initialize django is based in the django module itself. Take a look into your python site packages and within the django folder go to `django/views/templates/default_urlconf.html`

Comment: @MagicHat, note that this file shouldn't be modified, though. It's part of the Django library.